# How to load a custom page in a web view when there is no network connection

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I'm not an android developer I watched a few tutorials and completed the android webview application. I'm calling an internal file when there is no network connection available.

Everything is working fine for the first time when I open the app. But it's not working for below condition.

User opens the app with a network connection, inactive the network and click any of the website links. Then my HTML page is not calling. But the error message displays in the interface.

[image]

```
package com.afcholidays.splashscreen;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.onesignal.OneSignal;

public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView webview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    // OneSignal Initialization
    OneSignal.startInit(this)
            .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
            .unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true)
            .init();

    webview =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (url.startsWith("tel:") || url.startsWith("https://www.facebook.com/sharer") || url.startsWith("http://twitter.com/share") || url.startsWith("https://wa.me/") || url.startsWith("https://plus.google.com/share")){
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(intent);
                view.reload();
                return true;
            }
            webview.loadUrl("about:blank");
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
            //return false;
        }
    });
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            webview.loadUrl("about:blank");
            webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
            Toast.makeText(webview.getContext(), "Please check your network connection and try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
        }
    });

    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    webview.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
    //webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    webview.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webview.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webview.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
    webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webview.getSettings().setSavePassword(true);
    webview.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
    webview.getSettings().setEnableSmoothTransition(true);

    webview.setOverScrollMode(WebView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
    webview.loadUrl("https://www.websiteurl.com/");
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webview.isFocused() && webview.canGoBack()) {
            webview.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This bug is occurring because your code only checks if you're connected to wifi or mobile data - not if you actually connected to the web page.

You should be listening for your `webview` to throw an error. If it throws an error, just display the local page again.

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

@Override public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request,
      WebResourceError error) {
    super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
    // Load local page
    webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
  }
});
```

You can improve this code by checking if the error is "ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED" and then displaying the local page if true. This lets you handle all sorts of different errors!

Comment: thank you for your answer. I'm not an android developer I watched a few tutorials and completed the android webview application. Can you please modify the code and help me. I tried myself but it's showing some errors.